# How to write a functionin R to swaphalves eg: c(1,2,3,4,5,6) to c(4,5,6,3,2,1)

Tags: r

I want to write a function to swaphalves a vector of 6 elements,

But i want to swap the halves

Comment: what do you mean with "swap halves"?

Comment: I want to swap the elements of a vector for say c(1,2,3,4,5,6) to (4,5,6,3,2,1) thats like swapping the half elements of a vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply accomplished using median:

```
swap_fun <- function(x) {
   a <- median(x)
   c(x[x>a], rev(x[x<=a]))
}

swap_fun(1:6)
[1] 4 5 6 3 2 1
```